# Affordable infosec training for a small organisation

Tags: professional-education

Does anyone have any suggestions for infosec training for a small company (circa 7 employees).

I would be looking for general information security awareness plus specific training for securely working with databases (MySQL specifically).

Everything I've looked at is aimed at large organisations and is outside of our budget.

Comment: Hi i know that those are not a course but vulnhub and hackthebox are pretty good for learning pt and are all hands on

Comment: There are massive resources and libraries for free security awareness resources. "specific training for securely working with databases" is too undefined to be answerable, but if you can refine what you are searching for, then there are tons of free resources for that, too.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions of the type "where can I find product/service that does X?" are off-topic and the answers could go on forever.

Answer (score 1):

#### About the security awareness

Many governments publish infosec guidelines dedicated to companies.
Consider consulting:

- https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-50.pdf
- https://www.nist.gov/topics/cybersecurity/national-cyber-security-awareness-month/resources

#### About the technical skill

Many security challenge websites are free and let your employees learn a lot with fun. I think it's the perfect approach for a small company as this can be managed as a game during the breaks of the day.

I know root-me.org which has dedicated categories (web server, web client, app script, ...)

Another interesting freemium resource is https://pentesterlab.com/ which has a rich catalog of free infosec courses.

A more scholar approach should be to let your employee read the CIS benchmarks guidelines for servers and programs (including mysql) : https://www.cisecurity.org/benchmark/oracle_mysql/ (free but need registration) and the OWASP ASVS framework (for general purpose Web security): https://owasp.org/www-project-application-security-verification-standard/

Finally, you could register to a free (or paid if you have the budget) bug bounty program (hackerone, yogosha, openbugbounty, ...) and learn from the vulnerabilities found by the community.